# Android Snackbar undo delete does not reload the listview

Tags: android, reactive

I have implemented snackbar undo delete functionality in the fragment.It works fine .But now I have changed the how the menuoptions loads .I mean i added a condition that in a list of items when at least 1 item is checked delete icon shows up in menuitem otherwise  not .Sample

```
 @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);

    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    hideShowMenuItem();
    if (mItems.size() == 0)
        item.setVisible(false);

    else {
        item.setVisible(true);

    }

}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.checklist_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);


}
```

Everything looks good but now when I try to undo delete it does not load the view of the list.It does nothing.

```
 TravelmateSnackbars.createSnackBar(mChecklistView,
            R.string.deleted_task_message,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(R.string.undo, v -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
                    //adds all completed task in database again
                    ChecklistItem checklistItem = new ChecklistItem(mItems.get(i).getName(), String.valueOf(1));
                    mDisposable.add(mViewModel.insertItem(checklistItem)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe());
                    Log.i("CheckListItem ", "checklistItem " + checklistItem.getName());
                }
            })
            .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .show();

}
```

I am not sure whether adding condition in the menuoptions in the fragment is interfering with the view when undo is clicked .How snack bar reloads the listview of the items after we undo delete.?Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

After deleting/restoring a list item (like you are doing on the `undo` action) you should call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

Another problem is that, at least on the code you've posted, you are not notifying the adapter about list changed, and that's why you don't see it properly update.
After restoring/adding an item, you should call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter